# docker in linux EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, docker

I have installed docker from binaries in my Linux EC2 machine.Now everytime the server reboots i need to run below commands

```
 sudo docker &
 sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Otherwise it give me below error

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

So i have give the above mentioned commands in ec2-user data.But still its not working and i still need to run above commands manually.

Note below is not working for me,may be because i have installed from binaries and not using yum

```
 sudo groupadd docker
 sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
 su -s ${USER}
```

Comment: Welcome AWS_Beginner. You mention that something doesn't work, but didn't provide the exact error, which makes it really hard to help you. Also you mention `yum` but do not specify which OS and version you're running (yum is available on many distros, where each may need different solutions). Another good information would be how the service is being started at boot time. Is it `systemd`? `systemv`? manually? Which user owns `/var/run/docker.sock` and which permissions are set on it before you run your command? The steps you followed to install `docker` would also help.

Comment: @Zip Thanks.I have given exact error above.OS is RHEl 7.5.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/q/37227349/8438982

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instructions to [**Configure Docker to start on boot**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#configure-docker-to-start-on-boot)?

Anyway I suggest you start over, create a fresh new EC2 instance and **install docker with yum**. It will do all the right things for you.
Here are the instructions for [CentOS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/), for [Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) or for [Debian](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/).

Alternatively spin up the EC2 instance from [**ECS-optimised AMI**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html) that already comes with `docker` installed.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I cannot spin another instance due to limitations at my shop.OS is RHEL 7.5 and they have disabled yum.So i cannot install anything using yum.

Comment: `ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-141 ~]$ sudo systemctl enable docker`
`Failed to enable unit: Unit file docker.service does not exist.`
`[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-141 ~]$ ps -ef | grep docker`
root        1339    1310  0 06:08 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo dockerd
root        1341    1339  0 06:08 pts/0    00:00:00 dockerd
root        1347    1341  0 06:08 ?        00:00:00 docker-containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml
ec2-user    1598    1570  0 06:18 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto docker
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-141 ~]$`

Comment: @AWS_Beginner if your employer doesn’t give you the tools to do your job (ie `yum`) then it’s a hard call.